# Getting error Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, backend

I am working on a Django project. Two of the many models are `Story` and its `Part(s)`

Concerned serializers are as follows:

```
class StoryPartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content_length = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = ("external_id", "title", "published_on", "url", "content_length")
        read_only_fields = ("story",)

    def get_content_length(self, obj):
        return len(obj.content or "")
```

```
class StoryPartDetailSerializer(StoryPartSerializer):
    story_object = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = StoryPartSerializer.Meta.fields + (
            "story_object",
            "content",
        )
        read_only_fields = StoryPartSerializer.Meta.read_only_fields + (
            "external_id",
            "published_on",
            "last_worked_on",
        )

    def get_story_object(self, obj):
        story = obj.story
        serializer = StorySerializer(story)
        return serializer.data
```

So the aim is to fetch the respective `Part` with `Story` object inside it.
Simply fetching the part through `/story{story_url}/parts/{part_url}` works perfectly fine with the following output as example:

```
{
    "external_id": "fd9136e6-93a1-4dd0-b913-32ff8ee789c9",
    "title": "part title",
    "published_on": "2023-10-28T10:53:48.430132Z",
    "url": "26bAE54d",
    "content_length": 72,
    "story_object": {
        "external_id": "98d9509e-c26d-4a95-b693-45dc658924ca",
        "title": "TS6",
        "author": {
            "username": "testuser1",
            "about": "",
        },
        "description": "Description of TS6",
        "parts_order": [
            "DD4b7ceE"
        ],
        "parts": [
            {
                "external_id": "afbfd4ed-5bfb-4b0d-a812-4232010ffb09",
                "title": "Simple TEST",
                "published_on": "2023-10-09T01:32:53.015525Z",
                "url": "DD4b7ceE",
                "content_length": 5
            }
        ],
        "published_on": "2023-06-20T15:49:18Z",
        "url": "b950c1CF",
    },
    "content": "<img src='https://abc.test.net/9129e277-62ee-4897-b47a-492e8c6fff5c.png'>"
}
```

Problem arises in this code snippet where I am using signals to generate notification:

```
@receiver(
    post_save,
    sender=Clap,
    dispatch_uid="add_notification_clap",
)
def user_clapped(sender, instance: Clap, created, raw, **kwargs):
    if not created or raw:
        # Ignore if it's not a new Clap or if it's a raw signal
        return

    if instance.part and instance.clapper != instance.part.story.author:
        Notification.objects.create(
            user=instance.part.story.author,
            type=NotificationType.CLAP,
            content={
                "user": UserPublicSerializer(instance.clapper).data,
                "part": StoryPartDetailSerializer(instance.part).data,
            },
        )
```

Particularly in line `"part": StoryPartDetailSerializer(instance.part).data,` where I receive the error:

```
 raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable
```

It works fine if I just extract any one field of `story` object using `return serializer.data.get("title")`.

I suspect it is because of story object because by replacing `StoryPartDetailSerializer` with `StoryPartSerializer` works absolutely fine with the following sample output:

```
{
      "external_id": "2a17fe7a-9f35-48c9-a5d7-959d0efe8e0b",
      "type": 8,
      "read": false,
      "opened": false,
      "content": {
        "part": {
          "url": "26bAE54d",
          "title": "part title",
          "content": "<img src='https://abc.test.net/9129e277-62ee-4897-b47a-492e8c6fff5c.png'>",
          "external_id": "fd9136e6-93a1-4dd0-b913-32ff8ee789c9",
          "published_on": "2023-10-28T10:53:48.430132Z",
          "content_length": 72
        },
        "user": {
          "about": "",
          "username": "testuser2",
        }
      },
      "created_at": "2023-11-01T11:39:18.109735Z"
    },
```

Would be grateful for any help to include the whole story object inside part of notification content.